# Striping year from datetime in an sql query using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

i would like to perform a simple query in a csv file using SparkSQL.My code is this:

```
def format_date(date):
 return date

movies = spark.read.format('csv'). \
                options(header='false',
                inferSchema='true'). \
                load("hdfs://master:9000/movie_data_csv/movies.csv")


movies.registerTempTable("movies")
spark.udf.register("date_formatter", format_date)

sqlString = \
        "select date_formatter(_c3) as Year" + \
        "from movies " + \
        "limit 1"

res = spark.sql(sqlString)

res.show(res.count(),False)
```

My movies csv file contains a datetime object in column 3 as seen below:

```
Row(... _c3=datetime.datetime(1995, 10, 30, 0, 0),...)
```

What i would like to do is using format_date return and show "as Year" only the year from this datetime value.If i just use _c3 in my query it works fine showing the whole datetime value.Passing it to the function though produces this:

```
|java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Athens",offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=138,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Athens,offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=1972,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=28,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]|Tout Va Bien|0
```

Could someone explain to me what has happened here and how could i indeed return just the year using the format_date function?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `year` Spark SQL function to get the year. No need to write your own UDF.

```
sqlString = \
        "select year(_c3) as Year" + \
        "from movies " + \
        "limit 1"
```